# Hide Ionic(AngularJS) back button from appearing

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

Working on an iPhone app using the ionic framework(which is great). Currently im am using the `$state` variable to redirect usings, say 'on a successful login'.

I am writing this like so...

`$state.go("app.search");`

I have also tried

`$state.go("app.search", {}, {reload: true});`

Both of which correctly load the `/search` page but provide me with the back button at the top left with the menu.

Now i want the back button on the other functionality. I'm wondering if I need to call a different method to changes pages or if i can temporarily disable it on some views?

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late but in case someone else gets here looking for an answer, you can use the $ionicViewService as described below

```
    function controller($scope, $state, $ionicViewService) {
         $ionicViewService.nextViewOptions({disableBack: true});
         $state.go("app.search");
    }
```